# java script comparison for date; always showing message as current date is an earlier date

Tags: javascript

While selecting current date,show  the message as `You cannot select a day earlier than today`.

```
function checkDate(sender, args) {
    if (sender._selectedDate) < new Date()) {               
        alert("You cannot select a day earlier than today!");
        sender._selectedDate = new Date();               
        sender._textbox.set_Value(sender._selectedDate.format(sender._format))
    }
}
```

Comparison is not working properly.

Please help me.

Comment: you have a syntax error

Comment: is the sender._selectedDate a date object?

Comment: `if (sender._selectedDate) < new Date()) {`  change to `if (sender._selectedDate < new Date()) {`

Comment: `new Date()` always return date with time. Try `( new Date() ).getTime()` in console or anywhere and you can see date and time with miliseconds.

Comment: new Date() will result something  like this `Tue Sep 23 2014 19:44:06 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)`  Do you by any chance know the value of your `sender._selectedDate` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your `sender._selectedDate` has 0 for its hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds. The `new Date()` you are comparing it to will have hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds set to the current time, which is likely later than the `_selectedDate`. So, you should create the new date, and then set its hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds to 0. Then you can compare the dates properly. You can use `setHours()`, and pass in hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds. Also, thanks to @andrex for noticing that you also have a syntax error: remove the `)` after `sender._selectedDate.

```
function checkDate(sender, args) {
    var earliestDate = new Date();
    earliestDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    if (sender._selectedDate < earliestDate) {               
        alert("You cannot select a day earlier than today!");
        sender._selectedDate = earliestDate;               
        sender._textbox.set_Value(sender._selectedDate.format(sender._format));
    }
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. If this is the solution to your problem, then you should accept it as the answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the data of the date verification is used for so several solutions spring to mind.

Anyway I would divide the dates into its parts as (year/month/day/hours) etc and (+/-) find out if one or the other (year/month/day/hours) etc. doesnt compare or is earlier cq later then your checksum variable.

I gather you want to compare only (year/month/day) realy so when those check to be valid discard the rest!

`var dag = nu.getDate();
    var wkdag = nu.getDay();
    var maand = nu.getMonth();
    var jaar1 = nu.getYear();`

btw. Thinking about it, it makes a whole lot of difference if the form is checked right away or later, since more time that passes between validation of the function and sending the message, more chance of the date being earlier, if checked right away and using server time least chance of errors, but even then if send at 24:00 hours, validation of the date cq day will be done the next day. You may think of some code to put a stopper in the hole!